# Alternative to .NET WSE 3.0

Tags: web-services, soap, header

I'm using .NET 2.0. There are any alternative to .NET WSE 3.0?

Is it possible to pass username and password in soap header without any toolkit, only using code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(This suggestion might be way off, since I'm not sure if you mean some special WS.* headers, or just any custom header... and I've never heard of WSE)

I call a webservice with user/pass in a header as follows. It's not production code, but the snippets should illustrate it.

**On the client:**

```
string userName = "someusername";
string password = "somepass";

//create the custom header object
MyService.AuthHeader authHeader = new MyService.AuthHeader();
authHeader.UserName = userName;
authHeader.Password = password;

//create the WS-proxy
MyService.SomeWebservice someWS = new MyService.SomeWebservice();
//set headers
someWS.AuthHeaderValue = authHeader;
someWS.SomeMethod();
```

**The webservice:**

```
public class SomeWebservice : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public AuthHeader Authentication = null; //For receiving the authentication header from the SOAP client (you will never assign this property in user code, .NET handles the plumbing based on the [SoapHeader("Authentication")] attribute

    [WebMethod(Description = "Some webservice method")]
    [SoapHeader("Authentication")]
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        string suppliedUserName = Authentication.UserName;
        string suppliedPassword = Authentication.Password;
    }
}
```

**The AuthHeader class:** (defined at the "WS end")

```
public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public string UserName = null;
    public string Password = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to alter the SOAP Message using **SOAP Extensions** including the required **SOAP Header**